# What does, "Made it fashionable to be young" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

Major social changes in the 1960s **made it fashionable to be young.**

Would you please show me what does the bold part could mean?

Meanwhile, what does **it** refer to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The "it" refers to "to be young".

> Major social changes in the 1960s made being young fashionable.

As for the word "fashionable", though it usually means "of or relating to fashion", in this context it means "popular" or "desirable".

Comment: Any explanation for the down-vote?